# Split string to the right of delimiter

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to obtain the string to the right of the delimiter "|" and anything to the left can be ignored.

I tried the following, but it gives me the values to the left

```
  Dim s As String = "John Smith | 09F2"
    Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("|")))
    Console.WriteLine(s.Split(CChar("|"))(0))
    Console.ReadKey()
```

Result is: John Smith.  I want the 09F2 value.

I also tried the following lines of code:

```
   Dim strEmployeeInfo As String = cmbSelectEmployee.Text
        Dim employeeID = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(strEmployeeInfo, strEmployeeInfo.IndexOf("|"))
```

But the result of that is Smith | 09F2. Again I only need the 09F2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split on the `|` character, the resulting array will have "John Smith " in the first position, and " 09F2" in the second position. So you need to access the second position. Since it's 0-based pass in 1 to access the second position. Next, trim the result to get rid of any additional spaces:

```
Dim s As String = "John Smith | 09F2"
Dim split As String() = s.Split("|"c)
Dim result As String = split(1).Trim()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("|") + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have more than one "|" in your string and you want the last part after the last "|", you can use this and also it works for the above example:

```
Dim SArray() As String = s.Split("|"c);
//if necessary, check the length of SArray() for correctness
Console.WriteLine(SArray(SArray.Length - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this:

```
Dim s As String = "John Smith | 09F2"
Console.WriteLine(s.Split("|").Last().Trim())
```